Mysterious washer leak
I am trying to remedy two washing machine leaks, one mysterious, one not so mysterious.
First, the not so mysterious leak. When running a large load, water backs up and spills out the top of the box/pvc pipe that the washer drain hose is fed into. This connects to the pipe that the kitchen sink drains into, glugging sound can be heard from kitchen when washer is draining. I've disconnected and snaked the P-trap at the bottom of that pipe. What should I be attempting next?

Now, the mysterious leak. Running a small load does not result in water spilling out of the top of that box. However, I've kept noticing moisture on the floor even though the box and pipe connections feel dry. I just watched as the washer drained and the moisture started to appear without any leaks or drips. Somehow the water is coming from beneath the concrete slab? How/why is this happening, how/why to fix?



If the water is coming back up and leaks, clean the clog in the drain line

Unless the second leak is coming from the machine(unlikely)  then you probably have some cement cutting to do.

How is the gray fitting connected to the white ones, and connected to the stub out of the slab?

@Traveler I assume your suggestion is in regard to the first leak that I described. I've already cleaned the straight pipe, through the P-trap, and the connection to the main stack.

@crip659 I was worried about that possibility. How would I go about doing that, and what might I expect to find?

@Huesmann I'm not sure how they are connected. Just moved into this house this year, no idea when/how this fittings were assembled. None of those connections are visibly leaking though.

Most of the tools(cement saw) can be rented.  Will need to see what the problem is first.  Might just be a loose joint that needs sealing to broken/cracked pipe.
